# How to get file name without extension with using Regular Expressions

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, regexp-substr

I have a field with following values, now i want to extract only those rows with "xyz" in the field value mentioned below, can you please help?

```
        Mydata_xyz_aug21


        Mydata2_zzz_aug22


        Mydata3_xyz_aug33
```

One more requirement

I want to extract only  "aIBM_MyProjectFile" from following string below, can you please help me with this?

finaldata/mydata/aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld

I've tried this but it didn't work.

```
select 
regexp_substr('FinalProject/MyProject/aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld','([^/]*)[\.]') exp 
from dual;
```

Comment: didn't work @ran_0315 returned aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld But, I want to get only aIBM_MyProjectFile

Comment: Add some more sample data, and specify the expected result.

Comment: Try `WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (col, '^[^_]*_xyz_[^_]*$');` and `regexp_substr('FinalProject/MyProject/aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld','.*/([^.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew returned aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe in Oracle. Is there a way to get only the file name without its extension?

Comment: I updated my above comment suggestions, please check and let know if they work for you.

Comment: Thank you @WiktorStribiżew regexp_substr('FinalProject/MyProject/aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld','.*/([^.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) worked!  But, the first one did not worked . Could you please check this one. 
select regexp_substr('Mydata2_zzz_aug22','^[^_]*_xyz_[^_]*$') exp from dual; Did I do something wrong?

Comment: What do you mean to do with `regexp_substr` with `'^[^_]*_xyz_[^_]*$'`? What do you mean to get? A value between 2 `_`s? Try `regexp_substr('Mydata_xyz_aug21','_([^_]+)_', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: Try `regexp_substr('Mydata_xyz_aug21','_([^_]+)_', 1, 1, NULL, 1)`

Comment: Hi again @WiktorStribiżew. Regexp_substr is one of Oracle SQL regular expression functions. That returns the substring related with the pattern. For example I wanna get zzz from that string

Comment: Ok, but read your question, you are asking for something different (*i want to extract only those **rows***) - please update the question. You want to extract substrings between two underscores.

Comment: Both of them worked thank you so much @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract substrings between the first pair of underscores, you need to use

```
regexp_substr('Mydata_xyz_aug21','_([^_]+)_', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

To get the file name without the extension, you need

```
regexp_substr('FinalProject/MyProject/aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld','.*/([^.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

Note that each regex contains a capturing group (a pattern inside `(...)`) and this value is accessed with the last `1` argument to the `regexp_substr` function.

The `_([^_]+)_` pattern finds the first `_`, then places 1 or more chars other than `_` into Group 1 and then matches another `_`.

The `.*/([^.]+)` pattern matches the whole text up to the last `/`, then captures 1 or more chars other than `.` into Group 1 using `([^.]+)`.

Answer (score 0):

For the first requirement, it would suffice to use `LIKE`, as posted in answer above:

```
SELECT column
  FROM table
 WHERE column LIKE '%xyz%';
```

For your second requirement (extraction) you will have to use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` function:

```
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR ('FinalProject/MyProject/aIBM_MyProjectFile.exe.ld', '.*/([^.]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1) 
  FROM DUAL
```

I hope it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is to skip regexp completely:

```
WITH
    aset AS
        (SELECT 'with_extension.txt' txt FROM DUAL
         UNION ALL
         SELECT 'without_extension' FROM DUAL)
SELECT CASE
           WHEN INSTR (txt, '.', -1) > 0
           THEN
               SUBSTR (txt, 1, INSTR (txt, '.', -1) - 1)
           ELSE
               txt
       END
           txt
  FROM aset
```

The result of this is

```
with_extension
without_extension
```

A **BIG** Caveat where the regexp is better:

My method doesn't handle this case correctly:

> \this\is.a\test

So after I have gone to all this effort, stay with the regexp solutions. I'll leave this here so that others may learn from it.